# Android bottom toolbar disappears when fragment fills screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on an android app and am using a toolbar at the top of the screen and a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. I'm using a single activity to create the top and bottom toolbars and fragments to change the content between the toolbars. However, when the contents in the fragment go beyond the size of the screen, the bottom bar disappears.

Here is my home activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rentables.testcenter.HomeActivity">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <fragment android:name="com.rentables.testcenter.HomeFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_navigate"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_navigate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Im guessing it's because of the inner linear layout I have, but I wasn't sure how else to get the nav bar to stay static at the bottom. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just changed the whole thing to a relative layout, got rid of the inner linear layout, and instead of gravity I used alignParentBottom="true".